# How to response a fail on execute directmethod on device inside a job?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a job to invoke a direct-method on multiple devices. I force a fail on one device. The problem is: When I consult the statistics of the job, all devices answered succesfully.

Next text is the responsed by device when do filter by jobid:

```
Query device job response
{
  "jobId": "DHCMD520c3696-6bbd-4973-b50e-b7db9695e004",
  "createdTime": "May 16, 2018 2:57:39 PM",
  "startTime": "May 16, 2018 2:57:38 PM",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "May 16, 2018 2:59:27 PM",
  "endTime": "May 16, 2018 3:02:38 PM",
  "jobType": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
  "jobStatus": "completed",
  "deviceId": "dev05162018125626383",
  "outcome": "{\"status\":404,\"payload\":\"Failed\"}",
  "outcomeResult": {
    "status": 404,
    "payload": "Failed"
  }
}
Query device job response
{
  "jobId": "DHCMD520c3696-6bbd-4973-b50e-b7db9695e004",
  "createdTime": "May 16, 2018 2:57:39 PM",
  "startTime": "May 16, 2018 2:57:38 PM",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "May 16, 2018 2:59:26 PM",
  "endTime": "May 16, 2018 3:02:38 PM",
  "jobType": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
  "jobStatus": "completed",
  "deviceId": "dev05162018125626386",
  "outcome": "{\"status\":200,\"payload\":\"Started firmware update, download file: https://firmwareservice.blob.core.windows.net/firmwares/F_V03.04.005_MONITOR800.zip\"}",
  "outcomeResult": {
    "status": 200,
    "payload": "Firmware update"
  }
```

The first device response "400 failed" but the job status is "completed" not failed.

Next text is the responsed by job when do filter by jobid:

```
{
  "jobId": "DHCMD520c3696-6bbd-4973-b50e-b7db9695e004",
  "queryCondition": "connectionState = 'Connected'",
  "createdTime": "2018-05-16T12:57:38.899+0000",
  "startTime": "2018-05-16T12:57:38.562+0000",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": null,
  "endTime": "2018-05-16T12:59:50.764+0000",
  "maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 300,
  "jobType": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
  "jobStatus": "completed",
  "cloudToDeviceMethod": "{\"methodName\":\"runcommand\",\"responseTimeoutInSeconds\":200,\"connectTimeoutInSeconds\":5,\"payload\":{\"method\":\"firmwareUpdate\",\"URL\":\"https://firmwareservice.blob.core.windows.net/firmwares/F_V03.04.005_MONITOR800.zip\"}}",
  "updateTwin": null,
  "failureReason": null,
  "statusMessage": null,
  "jobStatistics": {
    "deviceCount": 2,
    "failedCount": 0,
    "succeededCount": 2,
    "runningCount": 0,
    "pendingCount": 0
  },
  "deviceId": null,
  "parentJobId": null,
  "outcome": null,
  "outcomeResult": null,
  "error": null
}
```

You can observe jobStatistics response 2 successful devices when one device response fail.

What should be the response of the direct method for the job to indicate that the device has failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I force a fail on one device.

You set status to "404" and send it with the job response like this right? (Code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-schedule-jobs#create-a-simulated-device-app).) Correct me if I am wrong.

```
string result = "'Failed'";
return Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result), 404));
```

Although you give a 404 error code but the device receive the job request and give a response successfully. The communication between the device and service back end complete without error. The error you set in the response payload you can work on it further as custom part if you need send more information. But it is another topic.

If you want to check the job failed case, you can stop the device after receive the job request before sending the response. so that it can't send response out. Then you can see "GatewayTimeout" error code and the job status is failed like this:

```
   {
    "deviceId": "device1",
    "jobId": "41c4727f-e723-4a9e-a5f3-a390a915610d",
    "jobType": "scheduleDeviceMethod",
    "status": "failed",
    "startTimeUtc": "2018-05-17T06:49:35.2555449Z",
    "endTimeUtc": "2018-05-17T06:51:35.2555449Z",
    "createdDateTimeUtc": "2018-05-17T06:49:38.2561206Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTimeUtc": "2018-05-17T06:49:43.2943762Z",
    "outcome": {
      "deviceMethodResponse": null
    },
    "error": {
      "code": "GatewayTimeout",
      "description": "Timed out waiting for the response from device."
    }
  }
```